# Difficulties to setup a Filter class

Tags: filter, modules, composer

*This question is following this one: [Where to implement Craft Webhook FilterInterface](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/38898/where-to-implement-craft-webhook-filterinterface/38899).*

I'm trying to implement a Craft Webhook FilterInterface but failed to load it.
Below is the content of my setup, which was initialized by `composer dump-autoload -a`.

**config/app.php**

```
<?php

use craft\helpers\App;

return [
    'id' => App::env('APP_ID') ?: 'CraftCMS',
    'modules' => [
        'utilities-module' => [
            'class' => \modules\utilitiesmodule\UtilitiesModule::class,
            'components' => [
                'companiesFilter' => [
                    'class' => 'modules\utilitiesmodule\filters\CompaniesFilter',
                ]
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'bootstrap' => ['utilities-module']
];
```

**composer.json**

```
[…]

"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "modules\\utilitiesmodule\\": "modules/utilitiesmodule/src/"
    }
}
```

**/modules/utilitiesmodule/src/UtilitiesModule.php**

```
<?php

use modules\utilitiesmodule\filters\CompaniesFilter as CompaniesFilter;

[…]

Event::on(
    Webhooks::class, 
    Webhooks::EVENT_REGISTER_FILTER_TYPES, 
    function(RegisterComponentTypesEvent $event) {
        $event->types[] = CompaniesFilter::class;
    }
);
```

**/modules/utilitiesmodule/src/filters/CompaniesFilter.php**

```
<?php

namespace modules\utilitiesmodule\filters;

use modules\utilitiesmodule\UtilitiesModule;

use craft\webhooks\filters\FilterInterface;
use craft\elements\Entry;
use yii\base\Event;

class CompaniesFilter extends BaseElementFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    public static function displayName(): string
    {
        return 'Entry has a “Companies” section';
    }

    public static function show(string $class, string $event): bool
    {
        // Only show this filter if the Sender Class is set to 'craft\elements\Entry' 
        return $class === Entry::class;
    }

    public static function check(Event $event, bool $value): bool
    {
        // Filter based on whether the entry's section is 'companies':
        /** @var Entry $entry */
        $entry = $event->sender;
        return ($entry->section->handle === 'companies') === $value;
    }
}
```

I'm getting a `Class 'modules\utilitiesmodule\filters\BaseElementFilter' not found` error.

**Stack trace**

```
Error: Class 'modules\utilitiesmodule\filters\BaseElementFilter' not found in /project/modules/utilitiesmodule/src/filters/CompaniesFilter.php:11
Stack trace:
#0 /project/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(476): include()
#1 /project/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(344): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('/Users/romainpo...')
#2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('modules\\utiliti...')
#3 /project/vendor/craftcms/webhooks/src/controllers/WebhooksController.php(89): spl_autoload_call('modules\\utiliti...')
#4 [internal function]: craft\webhooks\controllers\WebhooksController->craft\webhooks\controllers\{closure}('modules\\utiliti...')
#5 /project/vendor/craftcms/webhooks/src/controllers/WebhooksController.php(98): array_map(Object(Closure), Array)
#6 [internal function]: craft\webhooks\controllers\WebhooksController->actionEdit(4, NULL, Object(craft\webhooks\Webhook))
#7 /project/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#8 /project/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Controller.php(178): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#9 /project/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Module.php(552): yii\base\Controller->runAction('edit', Array)
#10 /project/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(287): yii\base\Module->runAction('webhooks/webhoo...', Array)
#11 /project/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/Application.php(103): craft\web\Application->runAction('webhooks/webhoo...', Array)
#12 /project/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(272): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#13 /project/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(384): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#14 /project/htdocs/index.php(26): yii\base\Application->run()
#15 {main}
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of this error to see where it's being thrown? Also, try leaving out the `components` definition in your `config/app.php` (you probably don't need this anyway) – does the error go away or change in any way?

Comment: I have updated the question with the stack trace. I also commented the `components` definition, but the error is still there.

Comment: Now the error message makes sense ;-) It's just a missing import statement, see my full answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error carefully; for some reason, PHP is looking for a class `modules\utilitiesmodule\filters\BaseElementFilter` which doesn't exist. The error message also tells you that the error is caused by this line:

```php
class CompaniesFilter extends BaseElementFilter implements FilterInterface
```

You want to extend `craft\webhooks\filters\BaseElementFilter`. But you have only specified the class name (`BaseElementFilter`), so PHP doesn't know to look in the `craft\webhooks\filters` namespace for that class. By default, class names are regular to the namespace the file is in, so `BaseElementFilter` expands to `modules\utilitiesmodule\filters\BaseElementFilter`. This class doesn't exist, so you get an error.

The solution is to either specify the fully-qualified namespace or [import the class name](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) using a `use` statement:

```php
use craft\webhooks\filters\BaseElementFilter;

class CompaniesFilter extends BaseElementFilter implements FilterInterface {}
```

Read the documentation on [importing / aliases](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) in PHP for more information.

Comment: I thought the `BaseElementFilter` class was from the Craft core, not from the Webhook plugin. Thank you for your precious help!